# Building Unity game for iOS platform with Asset Bundle

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

The problem that i have is that when i tried to build Unity game for iOS platform , I built the assets with it but then i need to reduce the file size as much as possible.

How do i split asset from the whole build ?
In Android, there's an option of using split binary application in player settings unity. However in iOS, there isn't any.

I tried to build Asset Bundle for iOS, it generated an asset bundle which to be uploaded to a server. 
Then if i build my game in Unity, it includes the assets and the file size will be just the same with without using Asset Bundle.

So what's the point of using Asset Bundle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity includes all scenes that are listed in the ["Build" window](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html) and all assets referenced in this scenes in the build.

If you want to exclude some assets and load them from the asset bundle instead, remove the scenes from the "Build" window and l[oad them from the asset bundle instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503085/unity3d-assetbundles-load-scene).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I store all my scenes into string array and build it as a Bundle Asset and upload it to a server. Then I call the url to retrieve the scenes.